# Show posts per page based on a media query?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I've got this loop of tile images on my Front Page (teasers) to the full list of content on another archive page.

**Styling as follows**

320px to 650px, the tiles are 100% of screen.

650px to 950px, the tiles are 50% of screen (2x side by side).

950px to max width, the tiles are 33.333% of screen (3x side by side).

Initially I had the **posts_per_page** set to **12**, so the grid format looked great with 2,3,6,9,12 all working fantastically in this layout.

However the client and I agreed there were too many tiles for a teaser, and he wanted to bring it back to **8 or 9** max.Problem is that in the 650px to 950px range, I now get the ugly single tile syndrome. As 9 is not being a multiple of 2.

Is there a way in the **(args)** code below, to arrange the posts per page based on media queries? Ideal situation would be 8 shown up to 950px and then **9 on larger screens**.

Appreciate any advice.

```
<?php
    $injuries_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'injuries',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '9'
    );
    $loop_one = new WP_Query($injuries_args);
?>
```

Comment: Php does not care about media queries, your front-end should trigger reload when special size is met.

Comment: You could load your grid via AJAX, passing a parameter to let PHP know the viewer's resolution and dynamically change the number of items... but that's not a great solution as it's not fully RWD friendly: if someone resizes the browser then you're back to the initial issue as items will look "ugly" again. A good compromise: talk to your client and suggest showing 6 posts instead (and make sure to explain to them why you're suggesting this.)

Comment: Ok, thank you, as suggested I'll pull back to 6 tiles. I was curious to know if it was possible another way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you could trigger an AJAX call to fetch the posts every time the window gets resized (well, **after** it gets resized for better performance) as Justinas above suggested to achieve what you want, but then you'd also need to update the pagination links (prev, next, 1, 2, 3, etc.) dynamically as well so the *next page* link lists the right posts. It's a hassle IMO haha but worth exploring if you're willing to go that route. (But if there's no next/prev pagination links after the grid then of course this isn't that much of a problem.)